# How to avoid bind(this) on every function?

Tags: javascript, bind

I'm implementing a web map client built on top of OpenLayers3 which should be able to connect to multiple WMS servers, ask for WMS Capabilities and show layers advertised by servers.

```
var MyMapClient = function(params) {
    this.wms_sources_ = params.wms_sources;
    this.wms_capabilities_ = [];
}

MyMapClient.prototype.parse_capabilities = function(index) {
    var capabilities = this.wms_capabilities_[index];
    // do something with capabilities 
}

MyMapClient.prototype.load_wms_capabilities = function() {
    var parser = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities();

    jQuery.each(this.wms_sources_, (function (index, wms_source) {

        console.log("Parsing " + wms_source.capabilities_url);

        jQuery.when(jQuery.ajax({
            url: wms_source.capabilities_url,
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
        })).then((function (response, status, jqXHR) {
            var result = parser.read(response);
            console.log("Parsed Capabilities, version " + result.version);
            this.wms_capabilities_[index] = result;
            return index;
        }).bind(this)).then(this.parse_capabilities.bind(this));

    }).bind(this));
};
```

The code above works fine but I have to `bind(this)` every time I want to call a function which needs access to "private" variables of `MyMapClient`'s instance. Isn't there a better way to access instance internals consistently, without sacrificing readability?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say to use the best of both worlds, that is, a local variable holding the correct scope, and calls to `bind()` where needed:

```
MyMapClient.prototype.load_wms_capabilities = function() {
    var parser = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities(),
        _this = this;

    jQuery.each(this.wms_sources_, function (index, wms_source) {
        console.log("Parsing " + wms_source.capabilities_url);

        jQuery.when(jQuery.ajax({
            url: wms_source.capabilities_url,
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
        })).then(function (response, status, jqXHR) {
            var result = parser.read(response);
            console.log("Parsed Capabilities, version " + result.version);
            _this.wms_capabilities_[index] = result;
            return index;
        }).then(
          function() { return _this.parse_capabilities(); }
          // or else
          // _this.parse_capabilities.bind(_this)
          // pick the one you like more
        );
    });
};
```

Comment: This won't work: the `this` inside `parse_capabilities` method would not be bound to the "instance" context but to the jQuery's context (because it's jQuery who calls `parse_capabilities`.

Comment: I'd already suggested this approach (now deleted) - OP says he's aware of this method (should probably edit that into the question) but wants to avoid if possible, and @deceze rightly pointed out "That doesn't help for `then(self.parse_capabilities)` at all"

Comment: Edited, should work now, less "beautiful" though... perhaps `bind()` would be just better.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Yes - I think a combination of storing a reference to `this` in the outermost scope along with calls to `.bind` where necessary (ie inside `.then()`) is probably the best approach here.

Comment: This looks like the cleanest/easiest to read approach to me now.  Unsure why it would attract a downvote...

Answer (score 1):

You can "hard bind" a method like this:

```
function Foo() {
    this.bar = this.bar.bind(this);
}

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
    return console.log(this.baz);
};
```

Incidentally, that's what [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org) compiles to when doing this:

```
class Foo
  bar: =>
    console.log @baz
```

The `=>` operator causes this preservation of context.

Comment: I'm still not sure how that helps with the `parse_capabilities` method on the prototype?  I think whatever the case, you'd still have to bind that in the call to `.then()`?

Comment: This works on `parse_capabilities` method. It cannot be applied to inner anonymous functions, though.